# Evaluating likelihood of egg breaking when falling in random container on concrete

Tags: time-series, data-mining, predictive-modeling, statistics, feature-engineering

I am working on a project where I would like to predict whether an egg will break if it is put in a container that is then dropped on concrete.

I am looking at the different factors that play a role in whether the egg will break. So far, I have come up with the following:

- mass
- friction
- padding
- shape of container

What other variables could help predict the outcome?

Comment: Hi, I have a hard time understanding how your tags relate to your question. Do you mind expanding a bit? Are you trying to simulate the behavior of the egg? or looking to put eggs in containers and throw them down from your window?

Comment: If I drop a raw egg out a window can it be predicted if the egg will break, based on shape of container, thickness and type of padding, etc.  Are there other elements?

Comment: Ok, so by performance, you mean the likelihood of the egg breaking?

Comment: Yes, can it be determined through tests and calculations?

Comment: I have edited your question, feel free to object if you don't think the update reflects your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might be better answered on the [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), but I'll take a *crack* at it.

Although the factors you mentioned probably affect the likelihood the egg will break, some of them are not specific enough to be descriptive features. For example, how do you quantify "shape"? I will try to provide some more features that can be quantified, but some of them might take effort to retrieve.

---

### Egg Features

- **Eggshell thickness**

  - the thickness will probably not be constant, so you can take the mean, standard deviation, and even isolate some key points on the egg to sample such as the top/bottom points.
  - some studies indicate that "eggs with thin but more uniform eggshell were stronger than those with thick but less uniform eggshell" [from this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/1828051X.2017.1344935)
  - you might be able to measure thickness using optical techniques such as imaging or lasers.
- **Temperature**

  - both of the egg and the surroundings
- **Time since egg was laid**

  - this might be approximated by the expiration date, particularly when only using a single brand
- **Density**

  - you can calculate this by putting the egg in water (fresh eggs sink) to first determine the volume, then divide the mass by this volume.
- **Calcium deposits**

  - the bumps you can see and sometimes feel on chicken eggs are calcium deposits that range in frequency and size. I am not sure how you would quantify these, but they could be another factor.

Wikipedia indicates some [abnormalities with eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_as_food#Abnormalities) that you might want to account for or remove from your samples. I copied the abnormalities here:

- **[double-yolk eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yolk#Double-yolk_eggs)**
- **[yolkless eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yolk#Yolkless_eggs)**
- **Double-shelled eggs:** where an egg may have two or more outer shells, is caused by a counter-peristalsis contraction and occurs when a second oocyte is released by the ovary before the first egg has completely traveled through the oviduct and been laid.
- **Shell-less or thin-shell eggs** possibly caused by [egg drop syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_drop_syndrome)

---

### Container Features

ideally the impact energy would not be absorbed by the egg, so somehow you need to measure this using estimates of the material metrics as well as shape parameters. One such measurement might be:

- **Average surface area that contacts the ground**

  - You might find looking at the container's convex hull useful for visualization purposes

Many other factors can contribute such as:

- **[Hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness)**
- **[Resilience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilience_(materials_science))**
- **[Elasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(physics))**
- **[Stiffness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness)**
- **[Ductility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductility)**

---

Lastly, there are probably many features that can be calculated by combining the egg and container, but those seem to be much more complicated. For example, measuring the amount of movement, on average, an egg can endure within a container by applying pressure to certain areas. I am not sure how you would easily extract these types of data, but they certainly exist.